# Операция с массивом

Tags: php

Добрый день! как такой массив

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [q_id] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [q_id] => 2
    )
)
```

сделать таким

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) - применяет callback-функцию ко всем элементам указанных массивов, возвращает массив, содержащий элементы входного массива после их обработки callback-функцией.:

```
$input = [
    ['q_id' => 111],
    ['q_id' => 222],    
];

$output = array_map(function($el){
   return $el['q_id'];
}, $input);
```

Comment: Благодарю, Алексей Шиманский!

Answer (score 0):

функция [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) извлекает значение столбца двумерного массива по ключу или индексу.

```
$input = [
     ['q_id' => 111],
     ['q_id' => 222],
];

$result = array_column($input, 'q_id');
```

Comment: А я думал `array_column` в итоге пробежится по столбцам с номерами 0,1 и т.д. и выдаст в качестве значений всё те же массивы, а на `q_id` будет ругаться, что нет такого столбца  у `$input` ....хм... странно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  дак 0,1 это не столбцы, а строки.

Comment: да я что-то подзабыл просто как это всё работает)